# What $\ln (x)$ has to do with $\pi (x)$ and why of all functions the $\ln (x)$ is there?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Prime number theorem is a statement that we have $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac {\pi(x)}{\dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}}=1$$.

> What has logarithm to do with number of prime numbers less than or equal to a given number and why of all the functions that could be there we have exactly $\ln(x)$?

It could be that there is something mysterious in this limit relationship not obvious at all, can someone tell me more?

For me, it is not at all obvious that asymptotically function $\pi(x) \cdot \ln(x)$ will grow almost exactly as $x$, one continuous and other discontinuous.

Comment: You don't have to have $x/\ln(x)$, you could have the logarithmic integral $\textrm{li}(x)$ instead.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with $$\frac{x}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}}.$$ ]

Comment: The actual answer to your question consists of a proof of the theorem...

Comment: As the old joke goes: "What does a drowning number theorist say? Log Log Log Log...."

Comment: (Also check out Rankin's prime-gap theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds)

Comment: @WillJagy Do you really believe that it is "luck?" That seems a fairly weird view of mathematics, and one which inhibits exploration. There is a reason the natural log comes up over and over in number theory, and it is weird to attribute it to "luck."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right, natural log comes because of some reasons, I doubt that there is just one reason, maybe I would like that there is just one. But it could be that there is just one, that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime. Then the product:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)$$

is the density of numbers that are not divisible by any $p_i,$ $i=1,\dots, n.$

This can be rewritten:

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(m)}{m}}$$ where $$f(m)=\begin{cases}1&m\text{ has only the }p_1,\dots,p_n\text{ as prime factors}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Note that, $f(m)=1$ for all $m<p_{n+1}.$

The key is then that $\sum_{m=1}^x\frac{1}{m}\approx \log x$.

How we formalize this is, of course, quite complicated, or we'd have a really easy proof of the prime number theorem.